# Sending email through nodemailer to forward email(forwardemail.net) connected to gmail

Tags: javascript, smtp, nodemailer, email

I managed to send a message with nodemailer to my gmail address, but I can't do it with my forward email.
Here's how it looks like for my gmail account

```
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: "smtp.gmail.com",
  port: 587,
  secure: false,
  auth: {
    user: mygmail@gmail.com,
    pass: myAppPassword
  }
});
```

What I want is to send mail with my forward email that is:

> mymail@mydomain.com,

which is connected to gmail account and was added with

> https://forwardemail.net/en

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you've been able to setup "Send email as" in Gmail using these [instructions](https://forwardemail.net/en/faq#how-to-send-mail-as-using-gmail) you'll have the credentials you'll need.

The `user` should just be the username of the gmail account without the `@gmail.com`. And the `pass` should be the one you generated at https://myaccount.google.com/apppasswords

Comment: I don't want to back there right now, but will I be able to send this mail as domainuser@mydomain.com, not gmailuser@gmail.com(because this one isn't a problem). Is that what you meant?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I mean! But for the transporter, you need to include the username of the gmail address. Then later, in the `transporter.sendMail()` fn you can set the `from` field with `domainuser@mydomain.com`.